# Get coordinates from a Tweet using the Twitter API

Tags: java, mongodb, twitter, unirest

I'm trying to correctly get information from tweets using the Twitter API and Java. I'm trying to get the exact coordinates from [this tweet](https://twitter.com/MMateos97/status/1212893878430420992?s=20) which have geo tag enabled.

From now, I've created the corresponding Java classes as the [documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/intro-to-tweet-json) dictates, but maybe I'm not understanding very well the Geo Objects, since neither the `coordinates`, `bounding_box` or `place` appear. My guess is that I'm not declaring correctly those classes.

**For the Tweet class:**

```
// Imports here

public class Tweet {

    @SerializedName("created_at")
    public String created_at;

    @SerializedName("id")
    public long id;

    // ... All the rest of the parameters

    @SerializedName("coordinates")
    public Coordinates coordinates;

    @SerializedName("place")
    public transient Place place;
```

**For the Coordinates class:**

```
// Imports here

public class Coordinates {

    @SerializedName("coordinates")
    public String coordinates;

    @SerializedName("type")
    public String type;
}
```

**For the Place class:**

```
// Imports here

public class Place {

    @SerializedName("id")
    public String id;

    @SerializedName("url")
    public String url;

    // ... All the rest of the parameters

    @SerializedName("bounding_box")
    public String bounding_box;

}
```

When I make a petition to get the json information from the linked tweet I get the following data, and as you can see the fields `coordinates` or `places` does not appear. If it is useful, I'm using MongoDB Java API to store the json files and its Java POJO manager.  You can find all the code here: https://github.com/marmatsan/theTrainEngine

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong("1212893878430420992"),
    "created_at" : "Fri Jan 03 00:30:09 +0000 2020",
    "favorite_count" : 0,
    "favorited" : false,
    "id_str" : "1212893878430420992",
    "is_quote_status" : false,
    "lang" : "en",
    "possibly_sensitive" : false,
    "quoted_status_id" : NumberLong(0),
    "quoted_status_id_str" : NumberLong(0),
    "reply_count" : 0,
    "retweet_count" : 0,
    "retweeted" : false,
    "source" : "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/android\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for Android</a>",
    "text" : "Test 1",
    "truncated" : "false",
    "user" : {
        "_id" : NumberLong(593955589),
        "created_at" : "Tue May 29 18:59:38 +0000 2012",
        "default_profile" : false,
        "default_profile_image" : false,
        "description" : "En búsqueda del verdadero camino del Tao estudiando Ingeniería en Tecnologías de Telecomunicación.",
        "favourites_count" : 7497,
        "followers_count" : 186,
        "friends_count" : 114,
        "id_str" : "593955589",
        "listed_count" : 5,
        "location" : "Salamanca/Toledo/Madrid",
        "name" : "Martín ",
        "profile_banner_url" : "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/593955589/1513111580",
        "profile_image_url_https" : "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1130587021678927874/50unsAd3_normal.png",
        "protected_att" : false,
        "screen_name" : "MMateos97",
        "statuses_count" : 19420,
        "url" : "https://github.com/marmatsan",
        "verified" : false
    }
}
```

**Edit:** As stated in the answer, the problem is of the implementation, because when I remove the `transient` modifier from the `Place` object the program does not work. If someone has a fix for this problem please leave it in the comments.

Comment: Did you try using Twitter4J (http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) instead of mapping the api yourself?

Comment: No since I wanted to have a more "low level" control, but it seems that I will have to use it at the end... (and I don't know how to use Twitter4j and MongoDB)

Comment: your tweet might not have that info in the JSON data. The twitter user has to opt in to have this data stored. check developer.twitter.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I request the status it has the correct fields for this status.

```
$ okurl https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show/1212893878430420992.json
...
"geo":null,
"coordinates":null,
"place":{"id":"fd110fb449209bc4","url":"https:\/\/api.twitter.com\/1.1\/geo\/id\/fd110fb449209bc4.json","place_type":"city","name":"Burguillos de Toledo"
```

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/geo-objects#tweet-exact

Read the difference between "Tweet with Twitter Place" and "Tweet with exact location".

I suspect your "transient" field is causing Mongo not to save this field.